# C Language, how do I print a pointer - incorrect output

Tags: c, list, pointers, printing, linked-list

I wrote an implementation of linked lists (with two points, one for the next value, and one for the previous value) in C language and I'm trying to test my code.

I checked that it scans and prints correctly, however, when I try to test the code I wrote to find a value in list, it returns incorrect output.

The code for find in list is:

```
node* find_in_list(node *anchor,data_type x)
{
    node *temp;
    int is_empty=0;
    is_empty=is_list_empty(anchor);
    if(is_empty)
        return NULL;
    temp=anchor->next;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data==x)
            return temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The code to check if the list is empty is

```
int is_list_empty(node *anchor)
{
    int boolean=0;
    if(anchor->next=NULL)
        boolean=1;
    return boolean;
}
```

It should be noted that anchor never changes. I define anchor as a node in the linked list that does not have an actual value, instead I just use it as a pointer to the first "real" node.

The void main is

```
#include "linked_list.h"
void main()
{
    data_type num;
    node *anchor;
    anchor=create_node();
    scan_list(anchor);
    printf("The list scanned is \n");
    print_list(anchor);
    printf("Enter the number you wish to find\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("The address of %d is\n",num);
    printf("%p",find_in_list(anchor,num));
    getch();
}
```

The scanning and printing are done properly. It does indeed print the correct list, but when I try to print the address of some value in the list (no matter what value I enter) it returns 000000.

What is the problem?

Comment: `if(anchor->next=NULL)` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks...I would have never found out that one :P its working now as intended.

Comment: Why `int is_empty=0; is_empty=is_list_empty(anchor); if(is_empty) return NULL;`? Why not `if (is_list_empty(anchor)) return NULL;`?

Comment: You should enable all warnings (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....)

Comment: The problem was that I wrote "=" instead of "==". consider this closed :) also fixed the is_empty issue Jashaszun suggested

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You should make that into an answer.

Comment: Yes you should. I will accept it :)

Comment: Note that `void main()` is only acceptable (under duress) on Windows with MSVC.  Also, the basic answer to the question "how to print a pointer" is "with the `"%p"` conversion specifier".  You should pass a `void *` strictly, though you'll pretty much always get away with passing an 'anything else pointer' too.  If you don't like what it does (its output is platform-specific, but it is usually hex in some shape or form), you can convert the pointer to a `uintptr_t` value and then format it with `PRIXPTR` (etc) from `<inttypes.h>`: `printf("Pointer is 0x%08" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)ptr);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you've already solved your problem, but ultimately a more straight forward algorithm may have prevented your issue in the first place.

From an elegance/beautiful/simplicity point-of-view, I'd re-write `find_in_list()` to be something like the following, after eliminating the `is_list_empty()` routine:

```
node* find_in_list(node *list,data_type x)
{
    for(;list;list=list->next)
        if(list->data==x)
          break;

    return list;
}
```

(edited to use for-loop)

Comment: The `if`/`do`/`while` construct is unnecessary - you get exact same thing if you move the `while` to the top of the block. In fact, you could even use a `for` loop to make it even simpler.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder about myself when digesting after lunch, I should have seen that.  Fixed it.